# Parsing error: Unexpected character '#' while declaring priavate member in JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, eslint

When using '#' to declare a private member in a javascript class, eslint throws an error `Parsing error: Unexpected character '#'`.

For eg.

```js
class Test{
  #priavteMember; //Parsing error: Unexpected character '#'
}
```

`eslint` configuration: .eslintrc.json

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "no-param-reassign": "off",
        "no-plusplus": "off",
        "no-nested-ternary": "off",
        "lines-between-class-members": "off"
    },
    "globals": {
        "root": "readonly",
        "app": "readonly",
        "db": "readonly"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Add this to .eslintrc.json

```json
{
  ...
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 13,
  },
  ...
}
```

Private member specifier was introduced in [ECMA](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#implementation-defined) version 13.

Comment: s/was introduced/will be introduced/. It's not yet been released :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `es2022` environment, which will automatically set the `ecmaVersion` parser option to 13, as indicated in the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments):

```js
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2022": true,
        "node": true
    },
```